# Jquery .after() add image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-after

I'm running a small website. I have an ajax shoutbox.

I have 3 different user class on my website, and on the shoutbox they have a different colors so people know whos who.

I made a supporter class too but thats not an user class, I can select if the user a supporter by checking a radio button yes or no.

And I would like to if the radio is checked yes a small image would appear after the users name.

With php I made it like this for just a test:

```
if(isset($GLOBALS['user']['supporter'])) {
 $support = 'the image here';
}
```

My question is: is it possible to make this in jquery?

For like:

```
if($('global here') == 'supporter') {
  $('class here').after('the image');
}
```

Can some one please give me a hint?

Comment: your can use  `.after('<img src="..." />);`

Comment: yes i know that, my problem is how can i make a global vairablie in jquery like in php

Comment: in javascript global variable is not prefaced with 'var' while local variable is. HOWEVER I strongly reccomend that you do NOT use global variables in either programming language as it's bad practice.

Comment: sorry i don't know PHP but it is simply javascript you can make `js` and link to HTML thus it would be globaly. and as @kissmyface said your can make `var global_` something different that local have not at most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first you would need to get the value of your checked radio.

```
supporter = $('#radioButton:checked').val();
```

Then just execute the code as you have written it assuming that the value of the yes checkbox is '1'...

```
if($(supporter == '1')) {
  $('.myClass').after('your markup');
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: works like a charm, thanks for your help and thank you for spending time on me

Comment: No problem, but do look into not using global variables (a.k.a Scope Abuse) you'll have a much better time :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you could do:

```
<input type='radio' name='supporter' value='1'>Yes
<input type='radio' name='supporter' value='2'>No
<img id='support' style='display:none' src='yourimage'>

$('input[name=supporter]').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == 1){
         $('#support').show();
    }else{
         $('#support').hide();
    }

});
```